# Understanding a destructor

Tags: c++

I have the following simple class `Foo`:

```
class Foo {

};
```

And I try to run the following Unit Test code:

```
Foo* foo = new Foo;

Assert::IsNotNull(foo);

delete foo;

Assert::IsNull(foo); //why is it not null?? I deleted it.
```

When I delete `foo` the memory for this object was freed, so that the `foo` should point to the `nullptr`.

Why the `foo` is not null after deleting it?

Comment: Use *smart pointers* to avoid unintentional memory leaks.

Answer (score 4):

Deleting will not change the value of the pointer, but only release the memory it points at. After deleting, the respective pointer is invalid. (deleting will also call the destructor).

Deleting a valid pointer must always succeed, otherwise it's undefined behavior.

Comment: If I delete other objects in a `Foo` destructor how can I unit test that they were indeed deleted without any memory leaks?

Comment: `delete` doesn't **only** release the memory; it also runs the destructor for the object (although in this case there is no destructor to run).

Comment: How do I Assert that the memory for `foo` was released?

Comment: @Humberd Why would you do that? That would be testing the compiler, and not your code. Do you also assert that after `int i = 42;`, `i == 42` holds?

Comment: @Angew Well, I don't know. I'm discovering more and more featuers of C++ and I thought there is also such a tool.

Comment: @Humberd If you really really need to assert it, why not go with smart pointers as already suggested? In your case, you can't check it. You'd need to rely on how you structure your code. You could run tools like valgrind, but those will of course only find issues during runtime. (That said, if you pay attention, you can work with raw pointers, just make sure where responsibilities lie)